execute sendAndConfirmTransaction in @solana/web3.js is need long time and got error like has expired: block height exceeded
i try to make endpoint in typescript using @solana/web3.js all function of my code is working fine except the sendAndConfirmTransaction i try is many time but i still got the same error i dont know is problem coming from rpc or something
this my code:
export class UnmintSingleWallet {
    private connection: Connection;
    private mainPayer: Keypair;
    private tokenAddress: PublicKey;

    constructor(rpc: string, privateKey: string, tokenAddress: string) {
        this.connection = new Connection(rpc)
        this.mainPayer = Keypair.fromSecretKey(bs58.decode(privateKey))
        this.tokenAddress = new PublicKey(tokenAddress)
    }

    async burnTokenAndUnmint(destinationSol: string) {
        const innerBurnToken = await this.burnTokenIntraction()
        const innerCloseTokenAccount = await this.closeTokenAccountIntraction(destinationSol)

        const modifyComputeUnits = ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitLimit({ 
            units: 300000
        });

        const addPriorityFee = ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitPrice({ 
            microLamports: 500000
        });
          

        const tx = new Transaction().add(modifyComputeUnits).add(addPriorityFee).add(innerBurnToken, innerCloseTokenAccount)
        
        // const latestBlockHash = await this.connection.getLatestBlockhash()
        // tx.recentBlockhash = latestBlockHash.blockhash
        // tx.sign(this.mainPayer)
        // tx.feePayer = this.mainPayer.publicKey
        // const signature = await this.connection.sendRawTransaction(tx.serialize())


        // const confirmStrategy: BlockheightBasedTransactionConfirmationStrategy = {
        //     blockhash: latestBlockHash.blockhash,
        //     lastValidBlockHeight: latestBlockHash.lastValidBlockHeight,
        //     signature: signature
        // }
        
        // const sign = await this.connection.confirmTransaction(confirmStrategy)
        
        const sign = sendAndConfirmTransaction(this.connection, tx, [this.mainPayer], {commitment: "confirmed", skipPreflight: true})
        return sign
    }

    async sendTokenAndUnmint(destinationToken: string, destinationSol: string) {
        const innerSendToken = await this.sendTokenIntraction(destinationToken)
        const innerCloseTokenAccount = await this.closeTokenAccountIntraction(destinationSol)

        const modifyComputeUnits = ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitLimit({ 
            units: 300000
        });

        const addPriorityFee = ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitPrice({ 
            microLamports: 500000
        });

        const tx = new Transaction().add(modifyComputeUnits).add(addPriorityFee).add(innerSendToken, innerCloseTokenAccount)

        console.log(tx)
        const sign = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(this.connection, tx, [this.mainPayer])
        
        return sign
    }


    private async burnTokenIntraction() {
        const fromTokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
            this.connection,
            this.mainPayer,
            this.tokenAddress,
            this.mainPayer.publicKey
        )

        const balance = await this.connection.getTokenAccountBalance(fromTokenAccount.address)

        const tx = createBurnCheckedInstruction(
            fromTokenAccount.address,
            this.tokenAddress,
            this.mainPayer.publicKey,
            fromTokenAccount.amount,
            balance.value.decimals
        )

        return tx
    }

    private async sendTokenIntraction(destination: string) {
        const [fromTokenAccount, toTokenAccount] = await Promise.all([
            getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
                this.connection,
                this.mainPayer,
                this.tokenAddress,
                this.mainPayer.publicKey
            ),

            getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
                this.connection,
                this.mainPayer,
                this.tokenAddress,
                new PublicKey(destination)
            ),

        ])

        const tx = createTransferInstruction(
            fromTokenAccount.address,
            toTokenAccount.address,
            this.mainPayer.publicKey,
            fromTokenAccount.amount
        )

        return tx
    }

    private async closeTokenAccountIntraction(destination: string) {
        const tokenAccount = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(new PublicKey(this.tokenAddress), this.mainPayer.publicKey)
        
        const innerInstraction = createCloseAccountInstruction(
            tokenAccount,
            new PublicKey(destination),
            this.mainPayer.publicKey
        )
        
        return innerInstraction
    }
}

the function burnTokenAndUnmint and sendTokenAndUnmint is same execute time is to long

Does this answer your question? How can I analyze the reason for frequent BlockHeightExceeded errors?
